# How do I show contact details using this binding approach in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

```
public function show(Contact $contact)
{
    return view('contacts.show', compact('contact'));
}
```

This method is not working, it's expecting me to pass in $id as the parameter, any help on how this particular method works. It worked for me in laravel 8, but not working in laravel 9.

Comment: Please read the documentation on [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding). You should have an associated Route for this method, with `/{contact}` instead of `/{id}` (you didn't actually include your `routes/web.php` file in your question, so we have to guess beyond that).